# how do i run jest test on a node_modules folder in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have added my own another project as a dependency. now it's on the node_modules folder now
[image]

how do I run test file on that folder when running the `npm test`

Comment: You do not run tests of a dependency. Every project usually only runs its own tests. library code is expected to be already tested. You should have already set up an own project where you develop your dependency and run the tests there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your needs are but this is wrong.
If you want your project to be a dependency there are other safest ways to do that.

For example, with yarn, you can install a package from your computer as a dependency.
Consider the following example: you have your `main-project`, in which you want to include your `sub-project`.

So, in your `main-project` directory you can run `yarn add ../path/to/sub-project` and yarn will copy the code of your `sub-project` into the `main-project`. In this way you can keep the code splitted in two different reporitories.

A better way, if your `sub-project` is on github, bitbucket or whatever, is to give to yarn the url of your repo.

Yarn will automatically clone the repo into your node_modules every time that you'll run `yarn`. You can also specify a specific commit to use.

Read more about that in the yarn documentation.